# Disable UI while showing progress ring Winrt C# app

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, progress-bar

In my winrt C# application I want to disable the user interaction while progress ring is showing and something is running in background.

Please let me know how we can achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: i dont know whether you can use it or not but have look at this http://thecodecentral.com/2008/01/17/a-yui-loading-panel-widget this is YUI stuff

Comment: Do you need something like a splash screen?

Answer (score 1):

Place your content inside a containing grid with one row and column and place your content inside this single cell (most likely inside another grid). Inside the containing grid, immediately below the "real" content but inside the same single cell, place a full-width, full-height transparent dummy grid whose visibility is bound to the visibility of the progress ring. With some tweaking, you should be able to get the dummy grid to capture all user input and to prevent it from getting to the "real" content. When the dummy grid's visibility is collapsed (i.e. when the progress ring is also collapsed), the "real" content will function as normal.

Answer (score 1):

As I have did this. I have created user control called CurtainUserControl with only grid inside:

```
    <Grid x:Name="curtainGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    </Grid>
```

and in code I can show it

```
        public void ShowCurtain()
    {
        CurtainUserControl guc = new CurtainUserControl();
        mainGrid.Children.Add(guc);
    }
```

and hide

```
        public void HideCurtain()
    {
        int childCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(mainGrid);
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
        {
            CurtainUserControl guc = mainGrid.Children.ElementAt(i) as CurtainUserControl;
            if (guc != null)
            {
                mainGrid.Children.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
     }
```